# rearrange data: convert from water year to calendar year

Tags: r, date, time-series, tidyr

I have a table with data from an stream gauge arranged as this:

```
  Water.Year   May   Jun   Jul   Aug    Sep    Oct    Nov   Dec   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr 
1  1953-1954 55.55 43.62 30.46 26.17  26.76  41.74  19.92 41.25 28.77 20.96 12.47 10.51
2  1954-1955 23.49 81.35 46.71 29.33  67.83 133.30  37.62 30.16 21.07 19.38 13.87 10.63
3  1955-1956  9.87 51.59 55.36 63.03 154.08  98.15 104.06 32.85 22.89 17.30 15.68 10.88

> data <- structure(list(Water.Year = structure(1:6, .Label = c("1953-1954", "1954-1955", "1955-1956", "1956-1957", "1957-1958", "1958-1959", "1959-1960", "1960-1961", "1961-1962", "1962-1963", "1963-1964", "1964-1965", "1965-1966", "1966-1967", "1967-1968", "1968-1969", "1969-1970", "1970-1971", "1971-1972", "1972-1973", "1973-1974", "1974-1975", "1975-1976", "1976-1977", "1977-1978", "1978-1979", "1979-1980", "1980-1981", "1981-1982", "1982-1983", "1983-1984", "1984-1985", "1985-1986", "1986-1987", "1987-1988", "1988-1989", "1989-1990", "1990-1991", "1991-1992", "1992-1993", "1993-1994", "1994-1995", "1995-1996", "1996-1997", "1997-1998", "1998-1999", "1999-2000", "2000-2001"), class = "factor"), May = c(55.55, 23.49, 9.87, 18.03, 17.46, 11.37), Jun = c(43.62, 81.35, 51.59, 28.61, 15.14, 29.48), Jul = c(30.46, 46.71, 55.36, 24.36, 20.09, 19.48), Ago = c(26.17, 29.33, 63.03, 22.01, 16.97, 16.86), Set = c(26.76, 67.83, 154.08, 28.51, 27.24, 21.01), Oct = c(41.74, 133.3, 98.15, 53.72, 35.78, 19.78), Nov = c(19.92, 37.62, 104.06, 115.78, 20.35, 18.69), Dic = c(41.25, 30.16, 32.85, 32.04, 22, 18.86), Ene = c(28.77, 21.07, 22.89, 25.44, 13.27, 14.89), Feb = c(20.96, 19.38, 17.3, 14.53, 10.37, 10.4), Mar = c(12.47, 13.87, 15.68, 10.78, 8.77, 8.79), Abr = c(10.51, 10.63, 10.88, 9.33, 7.69, 8.99)), .Names = c("Water.Year", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic", "Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

It is arranged by "water years", where each year starts in May and ends in April of the next year (this can be seen in the first column).
I want to convert it to a dataframe with three columns: ***Calendar.Year* -- *Month* -- *Flow.Measurement***

I already broke down the *Water.Year* column into two columns using "separate" from tidyr:

```
> df = separate(data, Water.Year, c("year1","year2"))

   year1 year2   May   Jun   Jul   Aug    Sep    Oct    Nov   Dec   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr 
 1  1953  1954 55.55 43.62 30.46 26.17  26.76  41.74  19.92 41.25 28.77 20.96 12.47 10.51
 2  1954  1955 23.49 81.35 46.71 29.33  67.83 133.30  37.62 30.16 21.07 19.38 13.87 10.63
```

Now I'm planning to use "gather" from tidyr to do the rest of the transformation but I'm stuck at how I can create a *Calendar.Year* column using *year1* for columns *May* to *Dec* and *year2* for *Jan* to *Apr*.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please use `dput(data)` to post a reproducible question. There is no good way to copy the data you provided as it is presented without manually typing them in.

Comment: `library(reshape2); melt(df)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use some pieces of all the answers I got.
This is the code I wrote:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#separate the year column into two years
df_years <- df %>%
  separate(Water.Year, c("Year1", "Year2")) 

#create two different dataframes for each section of the year
df1 <- subset(df_years, select = c(Year1, May:Dec))
df2 <- subset(df_years, select = c(Year2, Jan:Apr))

#rename both years' columns using the same name
colnames(df2)[1] <- "Year"
colnames(df1)[1] <- "Year"

#join both dataframes
cleandata <- full_join(df1, df2, by = "Year")

#sort months chronologically
cleandata <- cleandata[, c("Year", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")]

#convert to tidy data set
cleandata <- gather(cleandata, "Month", "Flow", 2:13)

#sort by year and month
cleandata <- arrange(cleandata, Year, Month)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another idea (using @useR data with English months)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


df %>%
  separate(Water.Year, c("Year1", "Year2")) %>%
  gather(Month, Value, -(Year1:Year2)) %>%
  group_by(Year1, Year2) %>%
  mutate(Year = if_else(match(Month, month.abb) >= 5, Year1, Year2),
         Month = factor(Month, levels = month.abb)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(Year, Month, Value) %>%
  arrange(Year, Month)
```

We separate the `Water.Year` column into `Year1` and `Year2` and we reshape the data into long format using `gather()`. Then, for each group, we use `match()` and `month.abb` to check if the month is greater or equal to 5 (May) and assign the corresponding year with `if_else()`. Finally, we remove unncessary columns and `arrange()` by `Year` and `Month`

```
## A tibble: 36 × 3
#    Year  Month Value
#   <chr> <fctr> <dbl>
#1   1953    May 55.55
#2   1953    Jun 43.62
#3   1953    Jul 30.46
#4   1953    Aug 26.17
#5   1953    Sep 26.76
#6   1953    Oct 41.74
#7   1953    Nov 19.92
#8   1953    Dec 41.25
#9   1954    Jan 28.77
#10  1954    Feb 20.96
## ... with 26 more rows
```

Comment: Great solution using `dplyr`! But the ordering of your final data is a bit off, since your "1953 Dec" does not follow up by "1954 Jan". Look at my solution.

Comment: @useR Oh, right ! Added the `factor()` part. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Ok how about this. It's a mashup between reshape and base R.

I used your dataset once you posted it. Thanks for providing it.

```
data <- structure(list(Water.Year = structure(1:6, .Label = c("1953-1954", "1954-1955", "1955-1956", "1956-1957", "1957-1958", "1958-1959", "1959-1960", "1960-1961", "1961-1962", "1962-1963", "1963-1964", "1964-1965", "1965-1966", "1966-1967", "1967-1968", "1968-1969", "1969-1970", "1970-1971", "1971-1972", "1972-1973", "1973-1974", "1974-1975", "1975-1976", "1976-1977", "1977-1978", "1978-1979", "1979-1980", "1980-1981", "1981-1982", "1982-1983", "1983-1984", "1984-1985", "1985-1986", "1986-1987", "1987-1988", "1988-1989", "1989-1990", "1990-1991", "1991-1992", "1992-1993", "1993-1994", "1994-1995", "1995-1996", "1996-1997", "1997-1998", "1998-1999", "1999-2000", "2000-2001"), class = "factor"), May = c(55.55, 23.49, 9.87, 18.03, 17.46, 11.37), Jun = c(43.62, 81.35, 51.59, 28.61, 15.14, 29.48), Jul = c(30.46, 46.71, 55.36, 24.36, 20.09, 19.48), Ago = c(26.17, 29.33, 63.03, 22.01, 16.97, 16.86), Set = c(26.76, 67.83, 154.08, 28.51, 27.24, 21.01), Oct = c(41.74, 133.3, 98.15, 53.72, 35.78, 19.78), Nov = c(19.92, 37.62, 104.06, 115.78, 20.35, 18.69), Dic = c(41.25, 30.16, 32.85, 32.04, 22, 18.86), Ene = c(28.77, 21.07, 22.89, 25.44, 13.27, 14.89), Feb = c(20.96, 19.38, 17.3, 14.53, 10.37, 10.4), Mar = c(12.47, 13.87, 15.68, 10.78, 8.77, 8.79), Abr = c(10.51, 10.63, 10.88, 9.33, 7.69, 8.99)), .Names = c("Water.Year", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic", "Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I decided to use the year information you had from before and just add in calendar year based on that. Since we know May-Dec is Year 1, and Jan-Apr is Year 2. Maybe a bit convoluted but it gets the job done.

```
df = separate(data, Water.Year, c("year1","year2"))

library(reshape2)

fixDF<-melt(df)


fixDF$CalendarYear<-rep(NA,nrow(fixDF))

fixDF$CalendarYear[min(which(fixDF$variable=="May")):max(which(fixDF$variable=="Dic"))]<-df$year1

fixDF$CalendarYear[min(which(fixDF$variable=="Ene")):max(which(fixDF$variable=="Abr"))]<-df$year2

fixDF<-fixDF[,3:5]

colnames(fixDF)<-c("Month","Flow.Measurement", "Calendar.Year")
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just realized the months you provided in `structure()` may be in a different language. I will just stick with the data I created, which uses the English version of Months. This way people can see the corresponding solution in English.

```
library(tidyr) # for separate function
library(reshape2) # for melt function
library(dplyr) # for pipe operator and arrange function

# Reproducible Data
weather = structure(list(Water.Year = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1953-1954", 
                                                      "1954-1955", "1955-1956"), class = "factor"), 
                         May = c(55.55, 23.49, 9.87), 
                         Jun = c(43.62, 81.35, 51.59), 
                         Jul = c(30.46, 46.71, 55.36), 
                         Aug = c(26.17, 29.33, 63.03), 
                         Sep = c(26.76, 67.83, 154.08), 
                         Oct = c(41.74, 133.3, 98.15), 
                         Nov = c(19.92, 37.62, 104.06), 
                         Dec = c(41.25, 30.16, 32.85), 
                         Jan = c(28.77, 21.07, 22.89), 
               Feb = c(20.96, 19.38, 17.3), Mar = c(12.47, 13.87, 15.68), 
               Apr = c(10.51, 10.63, 10.88)), .Names = c("Water.Year", "May", 
                                                         "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", 
                                                         "Mar", "Apr"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Coding starts here:

```
df = separate(weather, Water.Year, c("year1","year2"))

# Split into two datasets
columns1 = c("year1", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Dec")

df1 = subset(df, select = c(year1, May:Dec))
df2 = subset(df, select = c(year2, Jan:Apr))

longdf1 = melt(df1, variable.name = "Month", id.vars = "year1",
               value.name = "Flow.Measurement") 
names(longdf1)[1] = "Calendar.Year"
longdf2 = melt(df2, variable.name = "Month", id.vars = "year2",
               value.name = "Flow.Measurement") 
names(longdf2)[1] = "Calendar.Year"

# Combine the two datasets
final_df = rbind(longdf1, longdf2)

# Releveling the Month
final_df$Month = factor(final_df$Month, levels = month.abb)

final_df = arrange(final_df, Calendar.Year, Month)
```

Final dataframe:

```
> final_df
   Calendar.Year Month Flow.Measurement
1           1953   May            55.55
2           1953   Jun            43.62
3           1953   Jul            30.46
4           1953   Aug            26.17
5           1953   Sep            26.76
6           1953   Oct            41.74
7           1953   Nov            19.92
8           1953   Dec            41.25
9           1954   Jan            28.77
10          1954   Feb            20.96
11          1954   Mar            12.47
12          1954   Apr            10.51
13          1954   May            23.49
14          1954   Jun            81.35
15          1954   Jul            46.71
16          1954   Aug            29.33
17          1954   Sep            67.83
18          1954   Oct           133.30
19          1954   Nov            37.62
20          1954   Dec            30.16
21          1955   Jan            21.07
22          1955   Feb            19.38
23          1955   Mar            13.87
24          1955   Apr            10.63
25          1955   May             9.87
26          1955   Jun            51.59
27          1955   Jul            55.36
28          1955   Aug            63.03
29          1955   Sep           154.08
30          1955   Oct            98.15
31          1955   Nov           104.06
32          1955   Dec            32.85
33          1956   Jan            22.89
34          1956   Feb            17.30
35          1956   Mar            15.68
36          1956   Apr            10.88
```